# Asp:menu control css not working proper after publish and upload

Tags: asp.net, css, aspmenu

I'm developing and asp.net web application.In that application i uses an asp menu control and apply a css class to that menu control.Css works fine when i debug the project.
But after publishing and uploading on web hosting account.It doesn't show the css effects.

### My css class

```
.primaryStaticMenu
{
background-color: Transparent;
border:solid #D1FCFF 1px;
font-family :verdana , verdana_font;
font-size:inherit;
color:red;
}
.primaryStaticMenuItem
{
width: 8em;
border-right: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
padding: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0.2em;
font-family: verdana, verdana_font;
font-size: inherit;
    height: 25px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #78B7EF;
}
.primaryStaticHover
{
color: #800000;
border: 1px solid #74C4C1;
background-color: #9AC47D;
}
.primaryDynamicMenu
{   
    width: 18em;
border: 1px solid #D1FCFF;
font-family: verdana, verdana_font;
font-size: inherit;
color: Red;
background-color: #78B7EF;
}  
.primaryDynamicMenuItem
{
width: 18em;
height:1.8em;
padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
border: 1px solid #D1FCFF;
font-family: verdana, verdana_font;
font-size: inherit;
color: Red;
background-color: #78B7EF;
}    
.primaryDynamicHover
{
font-family :verdana , verdana_font;
font-size:inherit;
color:#AD0000;
border: 1px solid #74C4C1;
background-color: #9AC47D;
}
```

## Asp menu control

```
<asp:Menu id="menuPrimary" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlDataSource" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                           StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" StaticDisplayLevels="1" 
                           MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="5" CssClass="MyMenu">
                            <DataBindings>
                                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" ValueField="Tag" 
                                            NavigateUrlField="NavigateUrl" TargetField="TestTarget" 
                                            TextField="Text" ToolTipField="ToolTip" />
                            </DataBindings>
                        <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="primaryStaticMenu"/>
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="primaryStaticMenuItem"/>
                        <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="primaryStaticHover"/>   
                        <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicMenu" />     
                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicMenuItem"/>
                        <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicHover"/>
                       </asp:Menu>
```

### Local view

[image]

### After Uploading

[image]

Comment: have you used chrome or firefox's debugging tools to trace the css?

Comment: use firbug for firefox then let us know if the required css is loaded

Comment: Yes i checked css in firebug tool.
And also used chrome,Firefox,opera,safari and IE.
But result is same.

Comment: Problem is solved by adding controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"
in web config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by just adding controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" in web config file.

### Solution

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" >
  <controls>
    .......
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Now my menu control shows all effects.